AG Grid copy past but disable cell edit
we implemented a grid that allows copy paste from excel for multiple rows. It works great if you only "Click once" so that you are not editing the individual cell. But we noticed allot of users will double click into the cell and when they try and paste it puts everything in that one cell. This page is meant for a bulk copy paste section of rows only and no edit of cell values beyond that. Is there a way to disable entering the cell but still allow for copy paste? Thanks everyone!
We tried disabling the cell edit but then copy paste was disabled as well.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
